# Capture output of `jobs -p` into variable

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am using `shell` trying to capture list of background jobs:

```
sleep 11 | tee log_1.txt &
sleep 12 | tee log_2.txt &

jobs -p # this returns PIDs

X=$(jobs -p)
echo ${X}
```

Then I start it like this: `sh ./script.sh`

But for some reason I get nothing.

Trying to debug it I see that `jobs -p` actually returns the list of items.

Something like `X=$(ls -al)` also works as expected and the content is captured.

Comment: You tagged this `bash` but you're running it with `sh`. Which is it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I assign a value from a file to a variable in UNIX sh shell?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26590554/608639). The short answer is, use backticks.

Comment: @thatotherguy, yes sorry, probably I should not have don it but I worried that the question wont get enough attention. You are right, it is `/bin/dash`.

Comment: @jww, thank you for the reference, but backticks for some reason do not work with `jobs -p`, something like `ls -al` works but not `jobs`. I wonder what is special about that command.

Comment: `jobs` is an internal command (no subprocess knows the list of processes the shell has given status of process group leaders) so it's specific of the shell you are using.  Once said that, you can expect different behaviour from different shells to the `jobs -p` command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code works fine in `bash`:

```
$ bash myfile
10715
10717
10715 10717
$
```

But it does fail in `dash`, which is probably what your `sh` is:

```
$ dash myfile
11048
11046

$
```

(see [Why does my bash code fail when I run it with sh?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15179446/why-does-my-bash-code-fail-when-i-run-it-with-sh)).

`dash` is within its rights to behave this way (and Bash is arguably wrong) because [POSIX specifies](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/jobs.html) that "The jobs utility shall display the status of jobs that were started in the current shell environment", and you have created a new shell environment through your use of the subshelling `$(...)`.

If you want to do it in a `sh` compatible way you can redirect to a temp file and read that instead. Alternatively, you can collect the pids of each started background job using `$!`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I think redirection to a file will do it.
Though I switched to `bash` instead, I do not have much experience in Linux scripting and many things confuse me, probably I should have though about differences between the two before writing this :) Anyway, I ended up with code like this (\ is next line):
my-app | tee my.log & \
read -a PROCESSES <<< $(jobs -p)  \
PROC=(${PROCESSES[@]})  \
PID0=${PROC[0]}; \
PID1=${PROC[1]}; \

Comment: I could not use `$!` directly because since I pipe to `tee` I would get tee's PID. Also I should mention that I needed to start two apps in the background.
One of the options I considered was using `2>&1 > my.log` with following `tail -f my.log &` instead of `| tee ...`, but that's too much hassle, since I need to do it twice and then kill two more processes.

Comment: Also, POSIX doesn't force compliment with job control.  As optional, any vendor is free to include job control or not.

Answer (score 0):

In subshells, `jobs -p` will print only the *active* jobs. This means that:

```sh
true &
sleep 2 &
sleep 1
jobs=$(jobs -p)
```

will only capture the second job (since the first one will be finished).

To capture *all* jobs, including jobs finished but not waited for (zombies), do this:

```sh
# all jobs, simple variable
read jobs < <(jobs -p)

# all jobs, array variable
readarray -t jobs < <(jobs -p)
```